# useradd bash standard in syntax error

Tags: bash

```
store=$(cat /etc/passwd | grep ^$outName | awk '{print 1}' | cut -b4- | sort -n)
    #echo $store
    num=$(echo $store + 1 | bc )
```

`(standard_in) 1: syntax error
useradd: user 'cjh' already exists
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
useradd: user 'txj' already exists
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
useradd: user 'rbh' already exists
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
useradd: user 'cjh' already exists`

Where is the error I am missing? I want to increment a user name from `cjh1` if it exists already, to `cjh2...`

Comment: Oh my -- there's a *lot* wrong here. First, run `bash -x yourscript` to run it with full logging, which will show if (for example) you have DOS newlines.

Comment: Second, `'{print 1}'` is **not** `'{print $1}'`; you're literally printing `1`, not printing the actual username.

Comment: Third, if your OS is Linux, there are *much* better ways to tell if a user already exists. `getent passwd "$outName"` will look up the `/etc/passwd` entry directly, or fail with a nonzero exit status if one doesn't exist..

Comment: woops fixed that, still an error though. let me get the bash -x for you

Comment: getent will do the same thing as the code I have, just a little more efficiently?

Comment: Also, the use of `cat` here is needless -- `grep "^$outName" /etc/passwd` or `grep "^$outName" </etc/passwd` will do the job more efficiently, having `grep` read straight from the file itself, rather than reading from a pipe to a separate program that's reading the file.

Comment: ...reading for context, strike the `getent` suggestion.

Comment: i am still getting that illegal syntax error

Comment: I'm still waiting for the `bash -x` output to help you with that.

Comment: + readFile=info.txt
+ '[' '!' -f info.txt ']'
+ read -r var
++ sed -E 's/    /        x/'
++ echo 'CHrIS   john herzog  10001   Marketing'
++ awk '{print tolower($1)}'
+ fName=chris
++ echo 'CHrIS   john herzog  10001   Marketing'
++ sed -E 's/    /        x/'
++ awk '{print tolower($2)}'
+ mName=john
++ sed -E 's/    /        x/'
++ echo 'CHrIS   john herzog  10001   Marketing'
++ awk '{print tolower($3)}'
+ lName=herzog

Comment: it was really long

Comment: If you don't want to edit it into the question, consider https://gist.github.com/. Be sure to include the part with the actual syntax error itself.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/schnipdip/ec4e34e87c370f33ad9cb261e8000a97

Comment: The syntax error is from `bc`, not bash, because your `$store` is containing the whole line, not just the number.

Comment: well, the whole line after the first three characters that you're cutting off.

Comment: how do you suggest I store it then?

Comment: My suggestion is given in an answer -- instead of a cobbled-together pipeline, it's using bash built-in primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
maxNum=0
outName=cjh
while IFS=: read -r username _; do
  if [[ $username = "$outName"[[:digit:]]* ]]; then
    suffix=${username#"$outName"}
    if (( suffix > maxNum )); then
      maxNum=$(( suffix ))
    fi
  fi
done </etc/passwd
echo "New username is ${outName}$((maxNum + 1))"
```

See:

- [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) on reading input line-by-line in bash for an explanation of the `while read` idiom.
- [The bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for an explanation of the mechanism by which the suffix is extracted.